# how can i add class 2,5,8 etc number div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am creating gallery, bellow is sample html code

```
<div class="probox">
         <img src="pro/th/Chair.jpg" />
          <h2>Chair</h2>
      </div>


<div class="probox">
         <img src="pro/th/Chair.jpg" />
          <h2>Chair</h2>
      </div>


<div class="probox">
         <img src="pro/th/Chair.jpg" />
          <h2>Chair</h2>
      </div>

<div class="probox">
         <img src="pro/th/Chair.jpg" />
          <h2>Chair</h2>
      </div>


<div class="probox">
         <img src="pro/th/Chair.jpg" />
          <h2>Chair</h2>
      </div>



<div class="probox">
         <img src="pro/th/Chair.jpg" />
          <h2>Chair</h2>
      </div>



<div class="probox">
         <img src="pro/th/Chair.jpg" />
          <h2>Chair</h2>
      </div>


<div class="probox">
         <img src="pro/th/Chair.jpg" />
          <h2>Chair</h2>
      </div>
```

ok mainly in my page show 3 thumbnail each row, so i want to add class each row 2nd div.  like 1st row 2nd div 2nd row 2nd div... so it is mean 2nd div next 5th div next 8th div etc this way..

or if how can add class each 3rd div.. like 3rd div, 6th div, 9th div etc..

http://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/Wj5fd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
$('.productsarea .probox:nth-child(3n)').addClass('yourClass');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Wj5fd/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just Change Your Script as below :

```
jQuery('.productsarea').find('div.probox').each(function(i,e){
   if(i%3==0) $(e).addClass('last');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wj5fd/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the CSS selector: `selector:nth-of-type(formula)`. Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/km5hj/1/). If you want every 3rd div (or whatever your selector is) to have certain features, then you would use the following:

```
div:nth-of-type(3n) {
    //your CSS code here
}
```

The formula is of the form `an + b`, which is explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp). Basically, `b` is the offset and `a` is the slope (just like algebra). It uses index notation, so the first element fit by that selector is zero. So, if you want to hit every 3rd element starting after the second one, you would make the formula `3n + 1`.